# Backup ALL Photos & Videos properly from iPad?

Tags: video, backup

I have an iPad, and I want to back up all of my photos & videos from my iPad to the computer, I've tried FTP copying from the iPad to my PC, it didn't work out so well as some of the videos weren't loading properly, but the photo's worked, and, I've tried plugging the iPad into the PC and importing, with the same results. Help would be appreciated here, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy, a cloud service, has an app for iDevices that does complete automatic camera folder backups, and I have not had trouble with it at all as of yet. It's a cloud service: you get 15GB storage for free (20GB using [a referral link](https://copy.com?r=lbpFoQ)), and install the App onto your iDevice. If you install the Copy App onto your computer, too, then the entire Camera Folder you backed up with the iDevice App is downloaded into your Copy folder automatically.

This is the solution I would use; I'm sure there are several other ways of doing it too. It might solve your video playback troubles, but that might be another issue that isn't related to the backup.