# Backup Ubuntu using iPad

Tags: usb, backup, ipad

What is the best/correct way to transfer files from my machine (with Ubuntu 20.04) via USB to an iPad? I connected the iPad via USB, and I am not able to create any new folder under "Documents on user's iPad". I want to use the iPad to backup some files.

Comment: Use a cloud service perhaps? https://askubuntu.com/a/541961/307670

Comment: I would like to connect them via USB.